# How do I know what value I want for Volumes of CO2

Tags: carbonation, kegging, co2

I've bottled about 15-20 batches, but I am ready to keg for the first time. I see the table that has been rep[roduced on quite a few websites, and it has 3 examples with a range for the Volumes of CO2 desired. British, Most others, High Carb.

I'm assuming my blonde ale falls into the "Most other beers" category, but I dont know what value I want. Should I just set my CO2 at the mid range and hope for the best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a rather simplified set of guidelines for carbonation levels. [Different styles have different historical ranges of volumes of CO₂](http://www.brewboard.com/index.php?showtopic=105075&view=findpost&p=1295993). I'd start there (or from a similar source), and then use the PSI/temp/volumes table to find the right values.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for jsled!
Thanks!